# How to see and add to logs in libraries which are referenced in java spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, amazon-sqs, spring-bean

I have a spring boot application that uses the libraries: `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html) and `SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory` (https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-aws-messaging/2.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/cloud/aws/messaging/config/SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory.html). The application uses ASW SQS and Kafka but I'm experiencing some out of order data and trying to investigate why. Is there a way to view logging from the libraries? I know I cannot edit them directly but when I create the bean, I want to be able to see the logs from those two libraries and if possible to add to them.

Currently I'm setting up the bean in this way:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "application.listener-mode", havingValue = "SQS")
@Component
public class SqsConsumer {

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SqsConsumer.class);

    @Autowired
    private ConsumerMessageHandler consumerMessageHandler;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaProducer producer;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        logger.info("Loading SQS Listener Bean");
    }

    @SqsListener("${application.aws-iot.sqs-url}")
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        byte[] decodedValue = Base64.getDecoder().decode(message);
        consumerMessageHandler.handle(decodedValue, message);
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSqs);
        factory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10);
        factory.setWaitTimeOut(20);
        logger.info("Created simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory");
        logger.info(factory.toString());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

For reference, this is a method in the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`. It is these logs which I would like to investigate and potentially add to:

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (isQueueRunning()) {
                try {
                    ReceiveMessageResult receiveMessageResult = getAmazonSqs()
                            .receiveMessage(
                                    this.queueAttributes.getReceiveMessageRequest());
                    CountDownLatch messageBatchLatch = new CountDownLatch(
                            receiveMessageResult.getMessages().size());
                    for (Message message : receiveMessageResult.getMessages()) {
                        if (isQueueRunning()) {
                            MessageExecutor messageExecutor = new MessageExecutor(
                                    this.logicalQueueName, message, this.queueAttributes);
                            getTaskExecutor().execute(new SignalExecutingRunnable(
                                    messageBatchLatch, messageExecutor));
                        }
                        else {
                            messageBatchLatch.countDown();
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        messageBatchLatch.await();
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    getLogger().warn(
                            "An Exception occurred while polling queue '{}'. The failing operation will be "
                                    + "retried in {} milliseconds",
                            this.logicalQueueName, getBackOffTime(), e);
                    try {
                        // noinspection BusyWait
                        Thread.sleep(getBackOffTime());
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
            }

            SimpleMessageListenerContainer.this.scheduledFutureByQueue
                    .remove(this.logicalQueueName);
        }
```

How would I be able to see all of that logging from where I create the bean?
Any help would be much appreciated!